# Testng.xml in Intellij

Tags: xml, maven, intellij-idea, testng

Could anyone please let me know how to create testng.xml file in InelliJ , unlike Eclipse where it can be easily created by just right clicking.Please note that i am using Maven and not able to figure out how to create.Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-empty-files.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the IntelliJ plugin for TestNG does not have this capability. You would either need to create an empty xml and edit it accordingly to the TestNG DTD (or) make a copy of an existing testng suite xml file and then alter it according to your needs.

Comment: Yes I did the same..just manually create testng XML file and modified the contents from other XML from eclipse .I thought intellij is better editor but looking at this,eclipse looks better for testng atleast..Thanks for your answer!!!

Comment: The TestNG plugin for eclipse is built by the TestNG dev folks which is perhaps this was added into it. But since the IntelliJ plugin is created by the JetBrains team, that's probably why there's no parity. Maybe you can file a bug with JetBrains and see if this can be included. On a side note, if my answer was satisfactory, it would be good if you could please help accept it.

Comment: I was looking for a alternative if we have.I had already tried the same thing which you said.I will accept the  answer.Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ's latest version 2019.1.3 has this feature. You can add plugin named as "Create TestNG XML" and restart the IDE. Now you will be able to see the option "Create TestNG XML" by right-clicking at project or package or class level.